# Write a continuously differentiable function defined on the unit circle as difference of two holomorphic functions.

Tags: complex-analysis, cauchy-integral-formula

Given a $C^1$ function $g(z)$ on the unit circle, I would like to find $f^+$ holomorphic on $\mathbb D$ and continuous on $\overline{\mathbb D}$, $f^-$ holomorphic on $\mathbb C\setminus \overline{\mathbb D}$ and continuous on $\mathbb C\setminus \mathbb D$ such that $g=f^+-f^-$ on $\mathbb S^1$.

I guess both $f^+$ and $f^-$ is given by the Cauchy integral formula $\frac{1}{2\pi i}\oint \frac{g(w)}{w-z}dw$. It is clear that $f^+$ and $f^-$ are holomorphic on the interior and exterior of the disk, but it isn't clear to me how to show $f^+$ and $f^-$ are continuous at the boundary and their difference is $g$. The problem is $g$ is only a $C^1$ function but not a holomorphic function on a neighborhood of the unit circle. Can anyone help? Thanks.

Comment: Write the fourier series of $f$ as $\sum_{n \ge 0} a_ne^{int}+ \sum_{|n| <0} b_{|n|}e^{int}$ and define $h(z)=\sum a_nz^n, g(z)=\sum b_n/z^n, f=h+g$ on the circle etc